# My dog licks my other dog's mouth

Tags: dogs, behavior

I've recently realised that my black Labrador keeps licking my other dog's face when we give our other dog attention. This is causing no problems as it isn't hurting her, but I was just wondering: what may it mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a sign that the recipient of the licks is higher in the pecking order. The licks are a sign of submissive behaviour.